# Virtuemart Order list

Tags: e-commerce, virtuemart, webshop

ISSUE:

First time after adding the product to the cart and confirm purchase, we can see the order pending, in the LIST ORDER.

immediately on doing the above process for the second time and confirming the purchase, New order is replacing the previous pending order in the ORDER LIST.

On doing the above again, we see only the last generated order as pending and the previous ones are vanished.

Only if we provide a 90 seconds gap between two purchases, we see both the records in the order list as pending.

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 0):

VirtueMart has a feature to delete "pending" orders. To disable this, follow the below steps.

Open - **administrator/components/com_virtuemart/virtuemart.cfg**

Scroll down to the bottom of the file and add the following line at the very end -

```
reuseorders=0
```